# Measure-driven differential equations

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, ordinary-differential-equations

**Background:** I need some help to understand the concept behind measure-driven differential equations. The solution of an ordinary differential equation is continuous. In order to describe discontinuous trajectories we use the concept of *distributions* (very well described in the book "Functional Analysis" by W. Rudin). In brief, every function $x:\Re\to\Omega\subseteq \Re^n$ that is locally integrable over the open set $\Omega$ is mapped to a functional $T_x:\mathcal{D}(\Re^n)\to\Re^n$ as follows:

$$
T_x(\phi)= \int_\Omega x\phi d\mu
$$

where $\mathcal{D}(\Re^n)$ is the set of *test functions* (infinitely many times differentiable and with compact support). $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure over $\Omega$ - meaning that the integration is carried out in the Lebesgue sense.

Every distribution (i.e. a functional $T\in\mathcal{D}^\star(\Omega)$) has a derivative given by:

$$
(DT)(\phi)=-T(D\phi)
$$

In that sense we can construct generalized differential equations that look like:

$$
DT=g(T)
$$

Using this framework we can describe solutions that encounter jumps such as impulsive differential equations. This is accomplished using the Dirac functional $\delta(\phi)=\phi(0)$. (I don't want to go into much detail to keep the question short).

**The problem:** I recently stumbled on a thing called "Measure-driven differential equations". These have the form:

$$
dx=f(x(t),u(t))dt+g(x(t))d\mu(t)
$$

where $\mu:\mathcal{B}([t_0,t_1])\to\Re_+$ is a positive measure with the property $\mu(A)\in K$ for all $A\subseteq [t_0,t_1]$ where $K$ is compact. $u$ and $\mu$ here serve as external "signals". The solution of such an equation is reportedly:

$$
x(t)=x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^t f(x(s),u(s))ds + \int_{[t_0,t]}g(x(s))\mu(ds)
$$

(see [this article](http://www.dcce.ibilce.unesp.br/~gsilva/INVARIANCIA/inv_periodic.pdf) for example).

**The questions:** (i) I'm a bit puzzled with the notation $d\mu(t)$ and $\mu(ds)$. Can someone elaborate a bit on that? Since $\mu$ is a measure, what exactly is the meaning of $\mu(ds)$? (ii) Is there any advantage from using measures instead of distributions to describe phenomena with discontinuous trajectories? (iii) I would appreciate some reference (preferably a book) to get started with these things.

Comment: For (i), the Lebesgue integral of the function $f$ w.r.t. measure $\mu$ over the set $A$ is often denoted either by 
$$
  \int\limits_A d\mathrm d\mu
$$ 
or by 
$$
  \int\limits_A f(x)\mu(\mathrm dx).
$$ 
These notations are equivalent and are chosen based on personal preferences/notation convenience. I guess, when the measure-driven ODE is written, the form $\mathrm d\mu(t)$ is chosen to hold the similarity with $\mathrm dt$ (usual increment in ODEs) or $\mathrm dB_t$ (Brownian motion's increment in SDEs)

Comment: The first integral was meant to be $\int_A f\mathrm d\mu$

Answer (score -1):

Intuitively, if your variable $s$ is take in some $\Omega$ the notation $\mu(ds)$ means that you evaluate the measure on an infinitersimal segment $ds$ (you can think that like an open ball little as you want near $s=s*$) and you multiply this value with the value of the function evaluate in $s*$; so for example: $f(s*)\mu(ds)$, but this is just a particular notation because the true integral is the limsup of simplies function that approximate $f(s)$ with the necessary specification about sigma algebra ecc...
For the other question I can't help you now...